# I'm trying to use multiple layouts inside other layouts, but their content gets replaced?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

**TL;DR**
layout:

```
views
-login.blade.php
-layouts
 -a.blade.php
 -b.blade.php
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.a')

@section('content')
    login blade
@endsection
```

a.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.b')

@section('content')
    a blade
    @yield('content')
@endsection
```

b.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    b blade
    @yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

if you open the appropriate URL, this is what you see:

```
b blade login blade
```

so the `a blade`˛is replaced by the `login blade`.

**TS;DR**
I have this layout:

```
views
- login.blade.php
-layouts>
 -base_layout.blade.php
 -fullscreen_page.blade.php
 -no_nav.blade.php
```

It looks like this:

login

```php
@extends('layouts.fullscreen_page')

@section('content')
    <div class="shadow rounded-2 p-4 m-4 bg-white" style="min-width: 20vw; max-width: 90vw;">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <p class="text-muted">Welcome to the website.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control is-invalid" autocomplete="off"
                placeholder="E-mail">
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-floating mb-3">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control is-invalid" placeholder="Password">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary col-sm col-12">
    </div>
    <p class="text-muted">Copyright &copy; 2023</p>
@endsection
```

fullscreen

```php
@extends('layouts.no_nav_layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center"
        style="min-height: 100vh; background-color: #F6F9FF;">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
@endsection
```

no_nav

```php
@extends('layouts.base_layout')

@section('content')
    @yield('content')
@endsection
```

base_layout

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    @vite(['resources\css\app.css', 'resources\js\app.js'])
</head>

<body>
    @yield('content')
</body>

</html>
```

however, if I do as I pasted the code, the content of `fullscreen_page` will be replaced by the login's content.

I've looked at the `@parent` directive but that placed the login's content *below* the fullscreen's content, and I want to put it inside, not below it.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#stacks

Comment: Same result, but the fullscreen's content will be pushed below the login's content.

Answer (score 0):

The issue reason is due to that you're using the `@yield` directive inside nested layouts. To achieve what you want (login content goes inside the fullscreen_page content), you should use the `@parent` directive in conjunction with the `@section` directive. Make these changes in your codes:
fullscreen_page.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.no_nav_layout')

@section('content')
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center"
        style="min-height: 100vh; background-color: #F6F9FF;">
        @parent
    </div>
@endsection
```

no_nav.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.base_layout')

@section('content')
    @parent
@endsection
```